# Learning the haskell syntax

Tags: haskell

```
foo :: [Int] -> [Int]

foo (elem : rest)
    | elem == 0 && null rest = [elem]
    | null rest = [elem - 1]
    | elem == 0 = 0:(foo rest)
    | otherwise = elem - 1 : head rest + length rest : tail rest
```

I am studying Haskell. I am quite sure how the sample function above works.
I understand that `[Int] -> [Int]` indicates input type and return type.

What exactly is the (elem : rest)? Is it like a for loop?
And I know that `|` works like `if`, but I am quite confused because the syntax looks inconsistent.

Please help me understanding this function.

Comment: Is it time for [an introduction](http://learnyouahaskell.com)?

Comment: I am following that page, but understanding this specific function will give me better understanding.

Comment: Why not write another function using that syntax and experiment?

Comment: By the way, I personally dislike the code above, and I would not recommend you learn that style. It uses guards instead of proper pattern matching, relies on the partial `head,tail` (when pattern matching would avoid those! at least they are used safely here), calls `length` repeatedly causing a loss of efficiency. Finally, `foo` is still partial since `foo []` is undefined.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you need a tutorial, not a stack overflow answer, but I'll quickly breeze through the answers to your question: what is `(elem: rest)`.

First off, we're looking at pattern matching. Pattern matching breaks an argument into component parts based on matching values with constructors for its type. If that's confusing, it's only because you haven't used it much before. For a more straightforward example, imagine a custom data type:

```
data Foo = Foo Int
```

`Foo` here is just wrapping an `Int`, and we can pattern match on it by saying:

```
bar :: Foo -> Int
bar (Foo x) = x
```

This unwraps that `Int` by *pattern matching* with `Foo`'s constructor to assign the `Int` to `x`.

How is this relevant to the code above? Well a Haskell list has the constructor `(:)`. This is used as an operator, so you see it used infix rather than prefix (i.e. `3:something` rather than `: 3 something`, though you can do the latter if you enclose it in parens: `(:) 3 something` as with all operators). `(:)` is known as the "cons" operator, and it prepends something to the list.

If I were to re-write a list using `(:-:)` instead of `(:)`, I could write:

```
data MyList a = a :-: MyList
              | Null
```

This is a recursively-defined datatype, in that each element is either `Null`, or contains another `MyList` type. This is the same with lists: each element is defined as either `something : [moreSomethings]` or `[]`.

That first case there is special, and leads to what we're doing in `(elem:rest)`. We're splitting out the head of the list from the tail by pattern matching on the `(:)` operator. For list `lst`, `elem = head lst` and `rest = tail lst`.

This syntax is common everywhere, though you usally see it written as `(x:xs)` rather than `(elem:rest)`. Consider this transcription of `map`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

Literally this means to take the first element of the list you pass it, apply the function to it, and "cons" that to `map f xs` (mapping the same function over the rest of the list).

The only thing this is missing is a default case -- what happens when you get to the end of the list? Well we mentioned earlier that a list could either be `(x:xs)` or `[]`, so let's pattern match on `[]`

```
-- from above
map _ [] = []
```

Now the map of any function over an empty list is just an empty list. This is necessary because `map f (x:xs)` will not match against an empty list, and Haskell will complain that you have not written a total function, but a [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function).

---

Pattern matching is an exceptionally idiomatic Haskell construct, and you should use it a lot. For instance, you can parse `Char` digits 0-9 using:

```
-- |This is analogous to @digitToInt@ in @Data.Char@, but will not
-- parse hex digits ([a-fA-F]).
myDigitToInt :: Char -> Int
myDigitToInt '0' = 0
myDigitToInt '1' = 1
myDigitToInt '2' = 2
myDigitToInt '3' = 3
myDigitToInt '4' = 4
myDigitToInt '5' = 5
myDigitToInt '6' = 6
myDigitToInt '7' = 7
myDigitToInt '8' = 8
myDigitToInt '9' = 9
myDigitToInt _   = error "Invalid digit"
```

You can re-write your very strange function above using a bit more pattern matching:

```
foo' :: [Int] -> [Int]
foo' []         = []  -- zero-element list
foo' (0:xs)     = 0 : foo' rest  -- n-element list starting with zero
foo' [x]        = [x-1]  -- one-element list
foo' (x1:x2:xs) = (x1-1) : x2 + length xs + 1 : xs  -- n-element list
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foo :: [Int] -> [Int]

foo (elem : rest)
    | elem == 0 && null rest = [elem]
    | null rest = [elem - 1]
    | elem == 0 = 0:(foo rest)
    | otherwise = elem - 1 : head rest + length rest : tail rest
```

This is a case of two important concepts: Pattern matching and recursiveness. As mentioned above we are "breaking down" the components by saying how the input could look like.

```
foo :: [Int]->[Int]
foo (1:2:3:rest) = [rest]
```

In this case we say "if the input starts with a 1 followed by a 2 which is followed by a 3 which is followed by some rest **then do this.**

As you now can tell, the `: or "cons"` is an operator that works on lists by putting the argument to the front of a list with the same type.

Next thing is recursiveness. A recursive function is a different way of "looping" as we would call it in some other languages. We have an initial value, we do something with it, we apply that result to ourselves with updated arguments.

```
foo :: Int -> Int
foo 0       = 0
foo someInt = someInt + foo (someInt -1)
```

Here we will add the input together with the result of the same function with a decreased input value. When we hit the basecase 0 we will stop and return whatever the previous results are added with 0, and we return that value as a final result.

In your example we have only one recursive option, the rest are similar to a "base case" and will instantly return the value of the calculations as the final result

The recursive magic happends in this case when : `elem == 0 = 0:(foo rest)`

Now we know the things we need to know to break this function down.

```
foo (elem : rest)    -- if we have some elem followed by some rest
    | elem == 0 && null rest = [elem]    -- We call this the basecase of the recursive function
    | null rest = [elem -1]    -- whatever the value of elem is, if the rest does not exist, we return a list containing the elem decreased by one
    | elem == 0 = 0:(foo rest) -- whatever the rest, if elem equals 0, we take a zero and we add it in the front of whatever list comes out if we use the rest as the input argument to our function.
    | otherwise = elem -1 : head rest + length rest : tail rest
      -- in any other case not mentioned do the following: 
      -- take the first element of the rest, add it together with the lenght of the list, put that element in the front of the remaining elements of the rest, decrease the elem by one and put it in the front of that list
```

^ i hope this is not too hard to read